# Find the range of $y = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3 -x}$

Tags: functions

I have the function $y = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3 -x}$. The range in [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=range%20of%20sqrt(x)%2Bsqrt(3-x)%3Dy) is $y \in\mathbb R:  \sqrt{3} \leq y \leq  \sqrt{6}$

(solution after correction of @mathlove)

$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3 -x} = y$

$$
\begin{cases}
x \geq 0\\
x \leq 3
\end{cases}
$$

then

$(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3 -x})^2 = y^2$

$x+3-x+2\sqrt{x(3-x)}=y^2$

$2\sqrt{x(3-x)}=y^2-3$

irrational equation, therefore:

$$
\begin{cases}
y^2-3 \geq 0\\
4(3x-x^2)=(y^2-3)^2
\end{cases}
$$

The $y^2 \geq 3$ is verified when $y \leq -\sqrt{3}$ or $y \geq \sqrt{3}$

regarding the second element of the system $4(3x-x^2)=(y^2-3)^2$

$4(3x-x^2)=(y^2-3)^2$

$12x-4x^2=y^4+9-6y^2$

$12x-4x^2-y^4-9+6y^2 = 0$

$12x-4x^2-y^4-9+6y^2 = 0$

$4x^2-12x+y^4-6y^2+9 = 0$

the quadratic equation is verified when the discriminant is $\geq 0$, then

$b^2 - 4ac = (-12)^2-16(y^4-6y^2+9) \geq 0$

$144-16y^4+96y^2-144 \geq 0$

$16y^4-96y^2 \leq 0$

change $t=y^2$ and $t^2=y^4$

$16t^2-96t \leq 0$

the inequality is verified when $t_1 \leq t \leq t_2$ because the discriminant in t is $\geq 0$

$t(16t^2-96) = 0$

then

$t_1 = 0$ and $t_2 = 6$ but $t=y^2$ and

$\sqrt(0) \leq y \leq \sqrt{6}$

$-\sqrt{6} \leq y \leq \sqrt{6}$

Finally, the solutions in $y$ in the system are:

$y\leq -\sqrt{3}$ or $y\geq \sqrt{3}$ 
and
$-\sqrt{6} \leq y \leq \sqrt{6}$

the solutions in $y$ (=range) of the system is:

$\sqrt{3} \leq y \leq \sqrt{6}$ because the function in the domain is satisfy only for $0 \leq x \leq 3$

Comment: To obtain $\geq$ and $\leq$, type \geq and \leq, respectively, when you are in math mode.

Comment: Notice also that $y = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3 - x}$ is the sum of two non-negative numbers throughout its domain.

Comment: thanks Taussig: I noticed this, but I wish to show in a mathematical way

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus?

Comment: yes, sorry. Using calculus

Comment: @gianni You could also differentiate the function and study its variations.

Comment: @Gianni, see my answer for a calculus approach.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @Gianni: You are wrong at the very last step. We get $\sqrt 3\le y\le\sqrt 6$.

Comment: @mathlove could you edit on my post the error (and correct please!) for me and the comunity? thanks in advance

Comment: @Gianni: OK, done.

Comment: @mathlove, thanks!

Comment: @mathlove maybe there is an error when i say 0≤y≤sqrt(6) because is + and - sqrt(6). What do you think?

Comment: @Gianni: We have $y\ge 0, y^2-3\ge 0$ and $16y^4-96y^2\le 0$. And the third one is equivalent to $-\sqrt 6\le y\le \sqrt 6$ (do you see why?). It is not equivalent to $0\le y\le\sqrt 6$. That $y\ge 0$ comes from that $y=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3-x}$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $4x^2-12x+y^4-6y^2+9 = 0$
>
> the quadratic equation is verified when the discriminant is $>= 0$, then
>
> $b^2 - 4ac = (-12)^2-4(y^4-6y^2+9) >= 0$

This is the part where you have an error :
$$b^2-4ac=(-12)^2-4\cdot 4(y^4-6y^2+9)\ge 0$$
This is equivalent to $-\sqrt 6\le y\le \sqrt 6$.

With $y^2-3\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$, the range is $\sqrt 3\le y\le\sqrt 6$.

Comment: yes very true. Sorry!

Comment: What do you mean the quadratic equation is "verified"? Is the logic that the discriminant must be $\ge 0$ because we have to be able to isolate $x$ because we could isolate it in the original equation?

Comment: @Ovi: (The word you are talking about is the one the OP wrote.) $y=\sqrt x+\sqrt{3-x}$ is equivalent to $y^2-3\ge 0$ and $4(3x-x^2)=(y^2-3)^2$, i.e. $4x^2-12x+y^4-6y^2+9=0$.  We want this to have at least one real $x$, so $\Delta\ge 0$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes thank you it helps. I was (and still am) a little shocked that you can get two different pieces of information from a system of equations whose equation and inequality come from the same thing. I was expecting you would get exactly the same information from both.

Comment: Part 1: Sorry just one more question, how do we know that we are finished? From $4x^2-12x+(y^2-3)^2 \ge 0$ we get a restriction of of $144-16(y^2-3)^2 \ge 0$ $\implies$ $9 \ge(y^2-3)^2$ which yields $y \le \sqrt 6$ by choosing the positive root and $0 \le y$ by choosing the negative root, so we can establish $0 \le y \le \sqrt 6$, so from this we might naively conclude that the range is $[0, \sqrt 6]$. However, from another inequality in the OP, we saw that $y \ge \sqrt3$, so we conclude the range is $[\sqrt3, \sqrt6]$....

Comment: Part 2:...  However, how do we know that there isn't another restriction that we could find which would limit $y$ even more, perhaps to $y \ge 2$? Is it just because we know $f(0)= \sqrt3$, or is there a more subtle reason?

Comment: @Ovi: Ok, let me explain. Under the conditions $y\ge 0$ and $0\le x\le 3$, we know that $y=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{3-x}$ is **equivalent** to $y^2-3\ge 0$ and $4(3x-x^2)=(y^2-3)^2$. (Do you see why? This is a very important step in this method.) The last one can be written as $4x^2-12x+y^4-6y^2+9=0$. The condition that this has at least one real $x$ is $\Delta\ge 0$, i.e. $-\sqrt 6\le y\le\sqrt 6$. With $y\ge 0$ and $y^2-3\ge 0$, the range is $\sqrt 3\le y\le\sqrt 6$.

Comment: I was in the process of writing a comment, but it became so long that I decided to make it its own question. I would appreciate it if you could take a look :)  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784735/about-the-solution-to-finding-the-range-of-y-sqrt-x-sqrt3-x

Answer (score 2):

Note that $y$ is positive, and $$y^2=3+2\sqrt{x(3-x)}$$ It's clear from this that a minimum value for $y$ is $\sqrt{3}$.

Meanwhile, the largest that $x(3-x)$ can get is $\frac32\left(3-\frac32\right)$, since the expression $x(3-x)$ is quadratic with negative leading coefficient, and $x=\frac32$ is the axis of symmetry. So the maximum that $y^2$ can be is $3+2\sqrt{\frac32\left(3-\frac32\right)}=6$. Again since $y$ is positive, $y$ can maximally be $\sqrt{6}$.

Lastly since the function is continuous, the range is $\left[\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}\right]$, with $\sqrt{3}$ achieved at $x=0$ and $x=3$, and $\sqrt{6}$ achieved at $x=\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{3-x}$.  From this you have correctly deduced that the domain is $[0,3]$.

\begin{align*}
  f'(x) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt x} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3-x}}\\[0.3cm]
    &= \frac{\sqrt{3-x}}{2\sqrt x \sqrt{3-x}} - \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt x\sqrt{3-x}}
\end{align*}

$f'(x) = 0$ when $\sqrt{3-x} = \sqrt{x}$, which is when $x = 3/2$.  Also, $f'(x)$ is undefined when $x = 0$ or when $x=3$.  Luckily these coincide with the endpoints of the domain (which we'd also need to check separately if they didn't coincide).

So we have $f(0) = f(3) = \sqrt{3}$, and
$$ f(3/2) = \sqrt\frac{3}{2} + \sqrt\frac{3}{2} = \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{6}.$$

So the absolute min is $\sqrt{3}$ and the absolute max is $\sqrt{6}$.  Also, since the function is continuous on $[0,3]$ then by the Intermediate Value Theorem, the function attains every value between $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ for input values coming from $[0,3]$.  Therefore the range is $[\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}]$.