# find the result of $16y^4-96y^2 \leq 0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$16y^4-96y^2 \leq 0$

I have not clear the last step of this inequality to get the result $-\sqrt{6} \leq y \leq \sqrt{6}$.

Change $t=y^2$ and $t^2 = y^4$

$16t^2-96t \leq 0$

I compute the discriminant to understand when this inequality is verified

$b^2 - 4ac = (-96)^2 - 4 = 9212$

the discriminant is $\geq 0$ and the inequality is verified in $t_1 \leq t \leq t_2$. Then:

$t(16t-96) = 0$

where the solutions are $t_1 = 0$ and $t_2 = 6$. The inequality in t is verified for

$0 \leq t \leq 6$

$t^2$ is $x$ and then:

$0 \leq x^2 \leq 6$

$\sqrt{0} \leq x \leq + - \sqrt{6}$

from this step I can not justify why the result is  $-\sqrt{6} \leq y \leq \sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$16y^4-96y^2 \leq 0$

Suppose $y \neq 0$ (if $y=0$ you already know the result is true).

Then,

$16y^4-96y^2 \leq 0 \iff 16y^2 \leq 96 \iff y^2 \leq 6 \iff -\sqrt{6} \leq y \leq \sqrt{6}$

Comment: Thanks @Luisa. In other worlds is why -sqrt(6) =< y =< sqrt(6) meets also 0?

Comment: Yes! I just supposed that $y \neq 0$ to divide by $y^2$. To analyze the case $y=0$ just replace $0$ in the inequality and note that $0$ satifies!

Comment: Tahnks! now I have a problem to solve this :P with your conclusion http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783925/find-the-range-of-y-sqrtx-sqrt3-x

Answer (score 0):

Since you have $|y|^2=y^2\leq 6$, then this means that $|y|\leq \sqrt{6}$ and thus you can conclude that $$-\sqrt{6}\leq y \leq \sqrt{6}.$$